# Can't install modules globally

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install a package globally like this:

```
npm install -g yo
```

However, when I try to use it like this:

```
yo react-webpack
```

The package is not found:

```
bash: yo: command not found
```

I observed that `$NODE_PATH` didn't refer to anything so I changed it to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` and I repeated the process.

But I'm still getting the same error(the module is not found).

So how can I install the module globally?

Comment: Are you sure your module installed successfully. Try it with sudo command like "sudo npm install -g yo"

Comment: try a 'npm list -g' to see if the module was really installed succesfully.

Comment: You should observe errors that npm install writes to terminal. You shold probably run global install with sudo.

Comment: `npm list -g` does show that module

Comment: You probably need to adjust `$PATH` and add `/usr/local/bin` to it.